# Ошибка Heroku H14

Tags: python, развертывание, heroku

Всем привет. Пытаюсь задеплоить телеграмм бота, все сделал вроде правильно, но когда ввожу команду

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

выдает ошибку

> Scaling dynos... !
>    !    Couldn't find that process type (web).

В папке с основным скриптом так же имеется пустой **__init__.py**, **Procfile.windows**, **requirements.txt**.

В **Procfile** подобная запись

```
web: python bot.py
```

Команда

```
heroku ps
```

Выдает следующее:

> Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
>   Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
>   For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping
>
> No dynos on ⬢ serene-spire-81779

Comment: пробовал команду из справки [H14 - No web dynos running](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running): `heroku ps`? какой вывод?

Comment: Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

No dynos on ⬢ serene-spire-81779

Comment: добавь эту информацию в сам вопрос

Comment: а в гит это все пропушил?

Comment: Да, делал по гайду на сайте, т.к. в первый раз:   $ heroku login  
$ heroku create  
$ git push heroku master  
$ heroku ps:scale web=1  
$ heroku open

Comment: Попробуй сравнить шаги в [документации](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python), с тем, что у тебя есть, возможно просто пропустил что-то

Comment: Понял, спасибо, покопаюсь